# Proper way to refresh BindingDataSource, Context and Controls

Tags: c#, winforms, linq, linq-to-sql

This question may sound trivial but I'll ask it anyway. Given code below, what is the proper way to force `ListBox` to reflect new table content.

```
SQLDataContext dataContext = new SQLDataContext();
BindingDataSource myBindingDataSource = dataContext.MyTable1;
listBox1.DataSource = myBindingDataSource;
listBox1.DispalyMember = "Column1";
listBox.ValueMember = "Column2";

MyTable1 newRecord = new MyTable1();
newRecord.Column1 = "Some data";
newRecord.Column2 = 123;
dataContext.MyTable1.InsertOnSubmit(newRecord);
dataContext.SubmitChanges();
```

What is the most efficient way or best practice if you prefer, to force `listBox1` into reflecting `dataContext` changes?

Comment: This have already been asked a couple times in various variations, and solved in many different ways. Here's an example : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13879275/asp-net-listbox-datasource-and-databind

Have a nice day :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please do not get offended but this is a classic example of misusing collections. You are using 2 parallel collections and you can't expect one to know much about one another unles they are properly linked. Since you are binding `listBox1` to `BindingDataSource` you should perform add, remove and update operations on the same `BindingDataSource`. It binds both ways. Everything you add, update or delete from it will be reflected in bound controls and in the context. Just submit context changes and you will update the database. In your example, you bypass `BindingDataSource` and write directly to the context so `BindingDataSource' has no idea about the change.