# c# deleting database entries through list box

Tags: c#, asp.net, visual-studio-2012, listboxitem

I'm trying to delete rows from a table through a list box. Below is the code I used to display data from the database onto the list box. FYI - I'm using a calendar search function - whereby a user selects a date on the calendar, clicks 'search', and the list box displays the appropriate results based on the dates found in the DB.

```
Con.Open():
SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("Select Member, Clerk, Room, Time From Events where Date = @searchDate", con);
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@searchDate",SearchDate.SelectedDate);
IDataReader reader = cmd.ExecuteReader();

            while (reader.Read()){               
                string member = (string)reader["Member"];
                string clerk= (string)reader["Clerk"];
                string room = (string)reader["Room"];
                string time = (string)reader["Time"];
                lstEvents.Items.Add("Member: " + member + " -- " + "Clerk: " + clerk+ " -- " + "Room: " + room + " -- " + "Time: " + time);        
                //lstEvents is the ID of the listbox              
            } 
            reader.Close();
con.Close();
```

The above code works just fine. What I was hoping for was to find a way of deleting the corresponding row in the DB. So a user selects one of the returned items in the list and clicks 'delete'.  I got as far as...

```
SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("Delete From Events where Member, Clerk, Room, Date, Time = @member, @clerk, @room, @date, @time", con);
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@member", lstEvents.SelectedValue);
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@clerk", lstAppointments.SelectedValue);
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@room", lstEventss.SelectedValue);
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@date", Convert.ToDateTime(SearchDate.SelectedDate);
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@time", lstEvents.SelectedValue);

        cmd.Connection = con;
        cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
```

This attempt however kinda seems far fetched, any suggestions how this could be done? I don't particularly understand how I can select multiple values i.e. member and clerk from the same row in the list box.

Comment: Does this table have an ID?

Comment: yes, its an int that is automatically updated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you load rows from the database, also load the primary key (even if you do not display it).

When you delete something selected in your listbox, you can simply delete using the primary key.

If your table does not have a primary key, chances are very good that you should add one.

Comment: thankyou for that, i kinda understand what you are suggesting. The database does have a primary key, its an int that is automatically incremented by one. What i was particularly struggling with was finding out how I can extract elements from the selected item e.g. if i select a row in the list box, any ideas how i can reference the primary key related to that row? I've tried and failed with many attempts :/

Comment: You can use the `Tag` property to store the ID https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.frameworkelement.tag(v=vs.110).aspx

Answer (score 0):

Your best bet would be to use data binding, this is where you can create a list of objects which has an ID. The best way to do this would be to create a new class and give it the properties of the database:

```
public class MyClass
{
    public int Id {get; set;}
    public string Member {get; set;}
    public string Clerk {get; set;}
    public string Room {get; set;}
    public string Time {get; set;}
}
```

Once you have your object, you can "bind" this to a listboxitem control

[ASP.NET: Listbox datasource and databind](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13879275/asp-net-listbox-datasource-and-databind)

Once you have manage to bind your list object to your listboxitem control, you can do some code like this inside a button event

```
MyClass selectedItem = (MyClass)yourcontrolname.SelectedItem;
// do stuff with selectedItem.Id (like delete an entry from the database
```